# how to apply validation in AngularJS without form tag?

Tags: angularjs

I have a div in which I am not using the form tag and submit the form on ng-click button but how can I apply the validation of given filed in AngularJS.

```
<div ng-controller="AddNewvisaController">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="visa.requirement">
 <select ng-model="visa.country">
  <option value="1">abc<option>
    <option value="2">xyz<option>
     <option value="3">pqrs<option>
</select>
<button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitvisa()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the "ng-form" directive if you really dont want to add a form tag.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-form="myForm">
    <input type="text" required ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username">
    <button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">DO</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lb32DkXcCpfhVdfKNgBV?p=preview)

Comment: did you check out the example link? does it not work for you?

Comment: Himn tried you url but it is not working when i modified by below code

Answer (score 1):

You may try something below,

```js
var myValidationModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

myValidationModule.controller('AddNewvisaController', function($scope) {
  $scope.visa = {requirement : "", country : "pqrs"}
  
  //initilize to false - it will make sure the disable the submit button 
  $scope.enableSubmitButton = false;
  
  //Do the watch collection - whenever something changed, this will trigger and then do the validation as per the needs - here i validated as not empty - you can do whatever you wish and if everything is fine, then enable the button 
  $scope.$watchCollection(['requirement, country'], function(valueArray) {
    if(valueArray[0] != "" && valueArray[1] != "") {
     $scope.enableSubmitButton = true;
    } else {
      $scope.enableSubmitButton = false;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="AddNewvisaController">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="visa.requirement">
     <select ng-model="visa.country">
        <option value="1">abc<option>
        <option value="2">xyz<option>
        <option value="3">pqrs<option>
     </select>
   <button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitvisa()" ng-disable="!enableSubmitButton">Submit</button> <!-- introduce the disable directive to make is disable by default and this will acitve if all the required filed had met their validation 
  </div>
</div>
```